# Use back function in iphone with one hand

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I want to use back function in iphone in all apps with one hand. I can't swipe from left edge of the phone because I can't reach out to it with my finger. I also didn't want to use swipe down function. I need some way do this. On Android there was a separate button for back function. How can I do this? Maybe some app can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no “buttons” on an iPhone screen; this is by design.

I tested several apps on my iPhone (13 mini) and none require a swipe from the left edge rightward to “go back.”  This can be achieved with a rightward swipe from the center of the screen.

On Apple products, it’s more about the gesture than the actual location where you take the action. [Other than some very specific gestures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208204) like opening Control Center, unlocking the phone, and seeing notifications requiring the gesture to begin at a particular location, things like navigation or zoom are recognized anywhere on the screen.

> Gestures are a key way for people to interact with their touchscreen devices, eliciting a close personal connection with content and enhancing the sense of directly manipulating onscreen objects.

This is from the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/inputs/touchscreen-gestures) published by Apple.  More specifically, under *Best Practices* it states:

> **In general, respond to gestures in ways that are consistent with other apps**. People expect most gestures to work the same regardless of their current context.

It sounds as though the developers of the apps you are interested in/use have strayed from this design tenet.  From your comment that it’s pointless to contact the developers means they will never receive the necessary feedback to improve their apps.

It’s highly unlikely you’ll find an app to fix what other apps should have implemented in the first place.

Comment: Many apps doesn't support swipe from center or from near the edge of the screen. Only from edge of the screen. So i still need a solution of this.

Comment: File a bug report with the app developer.  When I tested, I randomly picked a random point but near the center to validate a one handed operation.  It worked every time.

Comment: Half of all apps doesn't support swipe from center. There is absolutely no point in writing to every developer. There is must be a way to do back function in other way.

Comment: I'm not looking the app that fix something. I maybe need an app that will simulate swipe in other way. Or maybe back arrow click simulate. Or maybe with some button like AssistantTouch i will be able to do back function. For now AssistantTouch doesn't have back function.